# Javascript check if value is in array inside array inside array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops

I'm doing one of my first real backend projects and I have a list of locations that looks like this:
Country(array) -> state (array) -> location(array) -> names (array)

What I want to do is take a given name, and then walk back up the tree and get its parent location/state/country.

For example the big apple (name) -> new york (location) -> state (new york) -> country  (usa)

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this without multiple loops?

I was thinking I could combine all locations and loop through,  find a match then keep going up doing the same thing?

Comment: Please post you data array, so that we can look what actually is required.

Comment: The names are unique across the whole data set?

Comment: Is it `locations = [{usa: [{ny: [{nyc: [{name: 'bigApple'}]}]}]`? An array of objects containing an array of objects...etc?

Comment: Yes names unique, ill post part of the data soon

Comment: @Purag exactly an array of objects, just like you have shown

Comment: Your title is inconsistent with your question. Your title says "check if value is in array". Yet your question seems to indicate you want to find the **path** to the value in the nested array. By the way, what is the problem with multiple loops? Since you have multiple arrays, multiple loop seems natural.

Comment: There no implicit link back to an array item's parent. You need to build that! Oh, and again - we need to actually see an example of the *code* - ie, the javascript array (or part of it at least)

Comment: What is *soon*?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is to store a string with the hierarchy of each element.

```
var hierarchy = 'Country|State|Location|Name';
var parts = hierarchy.split('|');
// parts.length will tell you what level of the hierarchy you are dealing with
var country = parts[0];
var state = parts[1];
var location = parts[2];
var name = parts[3];
```

Depending on your needs and the data source, the hierarchy string could be composed of the ids/index values at each level.